# Expression Engine - Layered Photo Gallery - Not sure how to build this

Tags: expressionengine

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to EE. Essentially what I have in front of me is a photo gallery with the following structure:

Gallery
-Section A
--Sub Section 1
--Sub Section 2
--Sub Section 3

-Section B
--Sub Section 4
--Sub Section 5
--etc

I see this function in way where the user navigates to the gallery page, is shown the two Sections (A,B) on the left, and a sample image from each of the Sub Sections(1,2,3,etc).

If they navigate to the Section page, they should see the same thing, except only that specific section.

Navigating to the sub-section from that point would display the same thing, but instead of only a sample image, the entire gallery of images is displayed (which then triggers a lightbox slideshow).

I am becoming utterly confused on how to set this up. I have tried a bunch of methods, some elements as categories, some as channels, related fields, etc, but I continually run in to a road block where I can't get the data I need because of EE's inability to nest channel entry tags, as ideally, the entire feature would be contained in a single template file.

The site currently has Structure, Matrix Fields, and Channel Images modules installed.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps in Expression Engine, but conceptually, this is called Faceted Search. Good examples of this type of search are Amazon, EBay etc. It is achieved by setting up metadata for each of your pictures and then organizing them as "taxonomies"

http://goo.gl/ROuCn

http://searchhub.org/dev/2009/09/02/faceted-search-with-solr/

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I would like to use the features inherent in Expression Engine without having to implement new technologies into the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it this way:

- Gallery is a channel
- Section A and Section B are Categories in that channel
- each Subsection is an entry
- the photos in each entry are controlled with a single Channel Images field (or alternately, a Matrix field with columns for images, caption, etc)

  ```
  {exp:channel:categories channel="gallery" style="linear" disable="category_fields"}
      <h1><a href="{path="gallery/section"}">{category_name}</a></h1>
      {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" category="{cat_id}" disable="member_data|pagination|categories" dynamic="no"}
      {if count == "1"}<ul>{/if}
      {exp:channel:images entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}
          <li><a href="{title_permalink="gallery/detail"}"><img src="{image:url:thumbnail}" alt="{image:title}" /></a></li>
      {if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
      {/exp:channel:entries}
  {/exp:channel:categories}
  ```

Your **gallery/section** template would then have the category information in the URL, so the Channel Entries tag there will automatically only show entries from that section/category. (Not sure if Strucure will interfere with this ... I'd suggest having these pages *not* managed by Structure.)

**gallery/detail** would just be a standard single-entry-style template, and you can list all of your thumbnails from your Channel Images field.

Comment: I'm going to have another shot at this today. Why would Structure affect this?

Comment: Because last I checked, Structure breaks EE's dynamic category filtering via URL segments.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work as the design dictated. I ended up just loading the various gallery cover photos/titles on one page, and then added in the images in a hidden div so that when a user clicks the cover image, it simply loads the colorbox slideshow. Leaving this open in case another solution comes along.